# How to write integer to binary file using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [using bash: write bit representation of integer to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746707/using-bash-write-bit-representation-of-integer-to-file)

I need to write the size of a file into a binary file. For example:

```
$ stat -c %s in.txt 
68187

$ stat -c %s in.txt >> out.bin
```

Instead of writing 68187 as a string to out.bin, i want to write it as a 4 bytes integer to out.bin.

Comment: it looks like a duplicate, but none of the answers there really solve this problem.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is what I could come up with:

```
int=65534
printf "0: %.8x" $int | xxd -r -g0 >>file
```

Now depending on endianness you might want to swap the byte order:

```
printf "0: %.8x" $int | sed -E 's/0: (..)(..)(..)(..)/0: \4\3\2\1/' | xxd -r -g0 >>file
```

Example (decoded, so it's visible):

```
printf "0: %.8x" 65534 | sed -E 's/0: (..)(..)(..)(..)/0: \4\3\2\1/' | xxd -r -g0 | xxd
0000000: feff 0000                                ....
```

This is for *unsigned* int, if the int is *signed and* the value is *negative* you have to compute the two's complement. Simple math.

Comment: Had never seen xxd.  And here I really thought there was finally something a little chain of commands couldn't do.... :)  (Edit: I feel like I should state that I did not down vote you.  Just figured I should say since it appeared right when I commented)

Comment: it didn't cross my mind it was you, but oooh maaan, who downvoted this? :/

Comment: I'd be quite curious to know.  I may be paranoid, but I swear lately people have gotten very down vote happy on perfectly fine answers.

Comment: +1 In ubuntu: `printf "%.8x" 65534 | xxd -r -p`

Comment: great! a minor issue, the sed ... should be: sed -e 's/0\: \\(..\\)\\(..\\)\\(..\\)\\(..\\)/0\: \4\3\2\1/' thanks a lot!

Comment: @Todd: not with the extended syntax (note: maybe your sed supports it with `-r`)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following function to convert a numeric VALUE into its corresponding character:

```
chr() {
  printf \\$(printf '%03o' $1)
}
```

You have to convert the byte values individually, after each other in the correct order (endianess) for the machine/architecture that you use. So I guess, a little use of another scripting language that supports binary output would do the job best.

Answer (score 2):

See if this works for you

```
perl -e "print pack('L',`stat -c %s in.txt`)">>out.bin
```

Comment: `pack` is quite versatile; if `'L'` doesn't do what you want, see t[he documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) for various other formats. There's also [a tutorial.](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html)