# Bash : echo binary output

Tags: bash, binary, echo, mode

for a script i must create a file and add a line (only numeric) to this.
But this should be in binary mode, but I havent found a solution.

My actually commands:

```
SIZE=200
touch quota
echo $SIZE >> quota
```

How can do this in binary mode?

Comment: What is "binary mode" supposed to mean?

Comment: a file can be created/uploaded in ASCII OR Binary Mode

Comment: That still means bupkis given that echo is generally for text.

Comment: I guess its a duplicate :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955020/bash-write-integer-to-binary-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to use the -n option?

```
echo -n "$SIZE" >> quota
```

Or maybe you need the binary representation it but this is only limited to 8 bits or 255.

```
echo -ne "$(printf '\\x%x' 200)" >> quota
```

Also make sure that you really need to use >> and not > as >> appends data to existing files, not overwrite it.