# Is it possible to write the binary representation of a number into a file using bash sript?

Tags: bash

I need to write the 4 bytes representation of a number (176) into a .bin file. I was using the following command

`perl -we 'print pack "N", shift' 176 >> package.bin`

and it works fine. But now I'd need to do exactly the same thing without using perl. Is it possible? I can only find solutions with perl but unfortunatly I can't use it because of project requirements.

I also tried this solution:

```
local n bit
for (( n=$1 ; n>0 ; n >>= 1 )); do  bit="$(( n&1 ))$bit"; done
echo -n -e $bit > tobin.bin
```

But it doesn't work because it writes `10110000` into my destination file and it is wrong because it is considered to be 8 bytes long and not 4 (1 byte for each character).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using bash: write bit representation of integer to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746707/using-bash-write-bit-representation-of-integer-to-file)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use `bc`, nor any oher exernal call.

Comment: @Harry : If you don't want to do **all** the mathematics by yourself, you could use `printf %xd 176`, which is an internal command, to turn the number into its hexadecimal representation, and then loop over each hex digits and use a static lookup table (array), to transform the hex digits into a string of binary digits.

Comment: This can also help you. It is also based on `printf`, which is a `bash` builtin: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92447/bash-script-to-get-ascii-values-for-alphabet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
num=176

printf -v oct0 '%03o' "$(( (num>>24) & 0xff ))"
printf -v oct1 '%03o' "$(( (num>>16) & 0xff ))"
printf -v oct2 '%03o' "$(( (num>> 8) & 0xff ))"
printf -v oct3 '%03o' "$(( num       & 0xff ))"

printf "\\$oct0\\$oct1\\$oct2\\$oct3" >package.bin
```

- You can set `num` to any 32-bit positive integer value.
- See [BashFAQ/071 (How do I convert an ASCII character to its decimal (or hexadecimal) value and back?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071) for details of how the conversion is done.